# How to create instructional Overlays in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am looking for guidance on how to create instructional overlays.  The ask is to display custom views as popup which have next button.

When popup is displayed it will reduce transparency of screen.  Also need to display animation for it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this component [JazzHands](https://components.xamarin.com/view/jazzhands) its more of a start screen Intro.

Other than that could you post some code of what you have tried? For iOS with a transparent overlay you could use modal view controller to present the instructional overlay, or you could just hide and show a uiview on top of your current view?

Modal Approach code within a VC:

```
var instructionalVC = new MyInstructionalViewController()
{
    // change these for different transitional animations
    ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet,
    ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
};
PresentViewController(instructionalVC, animated: true);
```

> Also need to display animation for it.

What kind of animation are you looking for?

Hope this helps.